# Search Bar results add image next to text

Tags: ios, swift

is it possible to add an image to my search bar results?  I'm able to add text using the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(self.identifier) as! UITableViewCell

var text: String?
    if tableView == self.searchResultsController?.tableView {
        if let results = self.results {
            text = self.results!.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
        }
    } else {
      //  text = MyVariables.users[indexPath.row] as? String
    }

    cell.textLabel!.text = text

    return cell
}
```

Comment: you have to add image view to your cell.

Comment: @T_77 After setting the image view how does the image know to go onto the left side of the text?

Comment: are you setting the image view programmatically?

Comment: yes, I'm getting it from an array in my db

Comment: I mean, are you setting the image view programmatically? I understood that u r getting the images from database.

Comment: how did you setup the text view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a `UIImage` to your cell.

```
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "YourImageNameGoesHere")
```

The `imageView` property of `UITableViewCell` is placed on the left.

> [...] If an image is set, it appears on the left
>   side of the cell, before any label. [...]

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/imageView

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, the image should appear on the left. Where do you want to place it?

Comment: I am sorry but you asked about how to display an image in your search results. Are you asking a different question now?